# php - black diamond question mark Issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, pdo

Okay. I searched for all possible methods. But this one still keeping me back.

I am using PDO to get the data from MySQL. MySQL data has chars like `ä`. I just run a query using PDO and `json_encode`'ing the resulting array. After encode, I `strip_tag`s.

When I print the array, I still see black diamond question mark char. �. 
`var_dump` shows the same diamond mark.

My PDO has the setting:

```
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
```

In the JSON response, I get `null` for the string that has this character.

I tried `utf8_encode`. It does not solve the problem. `utf8_encode(json_encode($results))`

I tried `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", strip_tags(json_encode($results)))`. No luck.

Database shows the correct character `ä`

I am completely out of ideas now.

**UPDATE:**

This solved my problem.

Changed this from:

```
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
```

To

```
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"
```

It works fine now.

Comment: Why are you doing `strip_tags()` on a JSON encoded string? Have you tried NOT doing that and see if that is what is causing your output to be corrupted?

Comment: you see it for only one character or for all of them?

Comment: Yes, already tried that too. No luck

Comment: @YourCommonSense wherever I see such chars, those are replaced by ONE diamond each.

Answer (score 1):

Black diamonds are browser issue. Database uses plain question marks.
It seems you are getting already wrong data from databalse. But that's quite tricky to have incorrect utf with your settings. You need to check everything

1. if your table marked with utf8 charset
2. if your data indeed encoded in utf (not marked but indeed encoded)
3. if your server sending correct charset in Content-type header.

it is also useful to see the page choosing different charsets from your browser menu.

**But first of all you have to wipe any trace of all random actions you tried**, all these various encode, decode and stuff. Just plain and direct output from database. Otherwise you will never get to the problem

Comment: `Just plain and direct output from database.` ==> Doesn't it mean print_r($results)? $results is an array returned directly from PDO query.